# Suggestions for our about page

Tags: discussion, site-settings

I just noticed that we can edit some parts of 
[the about page](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/about).
If you have a suggestion how to improve it please post it as an answer.

The parts we can edit are:

I. Introduction.

II. The example question displayed.

III. Ask about...

IV. Don't ask about...

Comment: I saw this on [MSO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/34570/) and liked it: "For questions of interest to professional/academic mathematicians"

Answer (score 2):

### Introduction:

#### September 20, 2013:

Added a link to CS.SE.

#### June 25, 2013:

Adding a link to our FAQ, plus some rewording.

> **Theoretical Computer Science - Stack Exchange** 
>   is a question and answer site for
>   *professional researchers in theoretical computer science* and 
>   related fields.
>
> It's built and run *by users* as a part of the 
>   [Stack Exchange](http://stackexchange.com) network of Q&A sites.
>   We welcome you to join us in asking and answering 
>   **research-level** questions in 
>   **theoretical** computer science.
>
> For **undergraduate-level questions**
>   please visit
>   [**Computer Science**](http://cs.stackexchange.com)
>   which has a broader scope.
>
> For more information about the scope
>   please check out our [FAQ](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

Currently they are as follows:

I. Introduction:

> **Theoretical Computer Science Stack Exchange** is a question and answer site for theoretical computer scientists and researchers in related fields. It's built and run *by you* as part of the [Stack Exchange](http://stackexchange.com) network of Q&A sites. With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about theoretical computer science.

II. The sample question displayed:

> [Coloring Planar Graphs](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/4027/coloring-planar-graphs)

III. Ask about:

> - Specific *research-level* questions in theoretical computer science

IV. Don't ask about:

> - Anything not directly related to theoretical computer science
> - Questions that are primarily opinion-based
> - Questions with too many possible answers or that would require an extremely long answer

Comment: Maybe also "Don't ask about things you'd encounter in an undergraduate CS class - CS.SE is a better place for that" ?

Comment: @Suresh, I also thought about that. I think it is good to have a link to [cs.se] there. I think your phrasing is a bit harsh though. Some brilliant undergraduates can have questions suitable for cstheory.